# PHP: DateTime throwing an exception with a legal timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

I don't get it:

```
$ts = strval( $this->get_start_date() ); // retrieve (int) timestamp from database

$time = new DateTime ( $ts ); 
    // throws an exception:  
    //'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string 
    //(1346284800) at position 7 (8): Unexpected character' 

$time = new DateTime();
$time->setTimestamp( $ts );
//works fine
```

Any idea what's going on here? I'm using

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:19:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize `DateTime` with UNIX_TIMESTAMP, use **@** at the beginning:

```
$time = new DateTime ('@'.$this->get_start_date());
```

See [compound formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) in PHP manual about formats which are accepted by `strtodate()` and `DateTime()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [DateTime::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php)

DateTime's constructor doesn't await a `unix timestamp` but a datetime string using the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Your second approach is just fine.